# Tail call optimization racket

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm trying to learn some functional programming and am doing project euler problems in scheme (racket) to get me started. I'm currently on [problem 15](http://projecteuler.net/problem=15) and I think I have a correct function for computing the number of paths in the lattice. Problem is that for large number of gridSize the function takes very long time to run.

```
(define uniqueTraverse
  (lambda (x y gridSize)
    (cond
      ((and (eq? x gridSize) (eq? y gridSize)) 1)
      ((eq? x gridSize) (uniqueTraverse x (+ y 1) gridSize))
      ((eq? y gridSize) (uniqueTraverse (+ x 1) y gridSize))
      (else (+ (uniqueTraverse (+ x 1) y gridSize)
               (uniqueTraverse x (+ y 1) gridSize))))))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make this function tail call recursive but I don't know how to do it. I need some help getting started on how to think about optimizing functions like this using tail call optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you recompute the same results over and over again.
To solve this, you don't need tail calls - you need to remember old 
results and return them without recomputing them. This technique is called memoization.

This is one solution:

```
#lang racket

(define old-results (make-hash))

(define uniqueTraverse
  (lambda (x y gridSize)
    (define old-result (hash-ref old-results (list x y) 'unknown))
    (cond 
      ; if the result is unknown, compute and remember it
      [(eq? old-result 'unknown)
       (define new-result
         (cond
           ((and (eq? x gridSize) (eq? y gridSize)) 1)
           ((eq? x gridSize) (uniqueTraverse x (+ y 1) gridSize))
           ((eq? y gridSize) (uniqueTraverse (+ x 1) y gridSize))
           (else (+ (uniqueTraverse (+ x 1) y gridSize)
                    (uniqueTraverse x (+ y 1) gridSize)))))
       (hash-set! old-results (list x y) new-result)
       new-result]
      ; otherwise just return the old result
      [else old-result])))

(uniqueTraverse 0 0 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Memoization is one way, another is to use a different data representation.

I used the grid represented as a matrix, or vector of vectors.

Then set the value of the top row to 1 (as there is only on path on the top edge.

After that the next row ther first of the row is one, the second is the value of the entry in the column one above, plus the entry of or value before it in the row,

Recurse for each of the points in the row, and then for each row.

The answer then is the last point in the last row when you are done recursing.

For a 3x3 grid

```
1 1 1
1 2 3
1 3 6
```

6

Where the keys are very close together, (continuous, or nearly so) a vector representation is going to be more performant than a hash.

```
(define (make-lattice-point-square n)
(let ((lps (make-vector (+ n 1))))
 (let loop ((i 0))
  (if (> i n)
      lps
      (begin
          (vector-set! lps i (make-vector (+ n 1)))
          (loop (++ i)))))))

(define (lattice-ref lat x y)
;; where x is row, y is column thought it's not really important
(vector-ref (vector-ref lat y) x)) 

(define (lattice-set! lat x y value)
 (vector-set! (vector-ref lat y) x value))

;; paths through a point are equal the the paths through the above point,
;; plus the paths through the left, those along the top and left edges 
;; only have one possible path through them

(define (ways-exit-lattice n)
 (let ((lps (make-lattice-point-square n)))
  (letrec 
    ((helper 
      (lambda (x y)
    (if (or (= x 0) (= y 0))
             (lattice-set! lps x y 1)
         (lattice-set! lps x y
                (+ (lattice-ref lps (- x 1) y)
              (lattice-ref lps x (- y 1)))))))
     (lattice-walker
      (lambda (x y)
      (cond ((and (= x n) (= y n)) 
                 (begin (helper x y) (lattice-ref lps x y)))
                ((= y n) 
                 (begin 
                  (helper x y)
                  (lattice-walker (++ x) 0)))
                (else 
                 (begin
                  (helper x y)
                  (lattice-walker x (++ y))))))))
   (lattice-walker 0 0))))
```

notice all the calls to latice-walker are tail calls.

using RSR5 compliant scheme

Comment: working by rows, you can conflate the previous row and the next row so all you need is one row, of _(n+1)_ `1`s initially, which you can then iterate over _n_ times, updating in place.